# Is it possible to find every occurrence of a particular variable being assigned to?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide, find-all-references

I am aware using 'Find all references' I can find every 'mention' of a variable - but is it possible to refine this search by only showing code that assigns a value to the variable in question?

For example:

```
var test = 1;
var test2 = test + 3;
test = 123;
```

Find all references with 'test' as the criteria would show all 3 lines.

The search I am after would show me only lines 1 and 3.

Comment: I'm sure some smart alec on this site will give you a *regular expression* for this; and I'll be first to upvote.

Comment: If you format correctly the code you could search for "test ="... with a space between t and the equal sign. I use to keep my code formatted because I often need such searches and I am not a guru in Regex. Regex can find for sure other assignments such as *=, += and so on.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @Bathsheba - updated tags. Apologies.

Comment: @DeeMac - that's ok; doesn't invalidate my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `test\s*=\s*.*;`? Use the find feature in the IDE and make sure *regular expression* is checked.

This will search for `test` followed by any amount of white space followed by = followed by any amount of white space followed by anything followed by `;`

It will fail on multiline stuff though; e.g.

```
test = \
123;
```

and the rather flashy *trigraph sequence*:

```
test = ??/
123;
```

although I'm not certain C# has either of these constructs.